# Set mappings depending on file type

Tags: key-bindings, filetype

I'd like to set some file-type dependent mappings to quickly run files. For example, I have some mappings like these:

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; gcc %; ./a.out<cr>
nnoremap <silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; g++ %; ./a.out<cr>
nnoremap <silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; ruby %<cr>
```

How can I set each mapping to its corresponding file type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FileType autocmd.

```
autocmd FileType c    nnoremap <buffer><silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; gcc %; ./a.out<cr>
autocmd FileType cpp  nnoremap <buffer><silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; g++ %; ./a.out<cr>
autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer><silent><leader>z :w<CR> :!clear; ruby %<cr>
```

See `:h autocmd` and `:h FileType` for more info.

Comment: So for a set of mappings for C, would I need to prefix every line with `autocmd FileType C` or is there a check I can do with `has()` or something similar?

Comment: `FileType C` will trigger for any files ending in .c

So yeah, that should work for your C files. You might add `H` as well.

Comment: Note the use of `<buffer>` - this is critical for getting it to work or the last one set (in this case ruby) will apply to all file types.

Comment: Of course, other types of mapping (e.g. `map` instead of `nnnoremap`) and other commands can be used; for example, I use: `au FileType python map <buffer><F6> :vert res 85<CR>` and `au FileType fortran map <buffer><F6> :vert res 138<CR>`